# Error from server (): the server could not find the requested resource

Tags: kubernetes

what is the error?
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
kubectl version is wriiten.

```
$kubectl version
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.0", GitCommit:"4ce5a8954017644c5420bae81d72b09b735c21f0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-05-03T13:46:05Z", GoVersion:"go1.18.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```